# Clone / Duplicate Linux (Mendel/Debian) platform image

Tags: linux, google

I'm currently developing a system based on the Coral Edgetpu Dev Board. Now we'd like to duplicate the system to identical other development boards. Can you recommend any tools (or maybe even commands) to create a new rootfs from the golden reference client.

I append the current flash script from the default distribution, in order to flash the board. At the end, the rootfs is flashed to the client, which we'd like to replace with the to be created rootfs from the golden client.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright 2018 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

function partition_table_image {
    if [[ $1 -gt 7000000000 ]] && [[ $1 -lt 8000000000 ]]; then
        echo "partition-table-8gb.img"
    elif [[ $1 -gt 14000000000 ]] && [[ $1 -lt 17000000000 ]]; then
        echo "partition-table-16gb.img"
    elif [[ $1 -gt 60000000000 ]]; then
        echo "partition-table-64gb.img"
    fi
}

function die {
    echo "$@" >/dev/stderr
    exit 1
}

function try {
    $@ || die "Failed to execute $@"
}

ROOTDIR=$(dirname $0)/..
SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

FASTBOOT_CMD="$(which fastboot)"
if [[ ! -x ${FASTBOOT_CMD} ]]; then
    die "Couldn't find fastboot on your PATH -- did you install it?"
fi

if [[ -n ${SERIAL} ]]; then
    FASTBOOT_CMD="fastboot -s ${SERIAL}"
fi

# Set USERSPACE_ARCH to arm64, if not set in the environment
USERSPACE_ARCH=${USERSPACE_ARCH:=arm64}

# If there's a boot.img in the same folder as flash.sh,
# find artifacts in the directory containing the script.
if [ -e ${SCRIPT_DIR}/boot_${USERSPACE_ARCH}.img ]; then
    PRODUCT_OUT=${SCRIPT_DIR}
else
    PRODUCT_OUT=${PRODUCT_OUT:=${ROOTDIR}/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell}
fi

# Figure out which partition map we need based upon fastboot vars
MMC_SIZE=$(${FASTBOOT_CMD} getvar mmc_size 2>&1 | awk '/mmc_size:/ { print $2 }')
PART_IMAGE=$(partition_table_image ${MMC_SIZE})

if [[ -z ${PART_IMAGE} ]]; then
    die "No partition map available for an emmc of size ${MMC_SIZE}"
fi

for i in u-boot.imx boot_${USERSPACE_ARCH}.img rootfs_${USERSPACE_ARCH}.img ${PART_IMAGE}; do
    [[ ! -f ${PRODUCT_OUT}/$i ]] && die "${PRODUCT_OUT}/$i is missing."
done

# Flash bootloader
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} flash bootloader0 ${PRODUCT_OUT}/u-boot.imx
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} reboot-bootloader
sleep 3

# Flash partition table
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} flash gpt ${PRODUCT_OUT}/${PART_IMAGE}
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} reboot-bootloader
sleep 3

# Flash filesystems
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} erase misc
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} flash boot ${PRODUCT_OUT}/boot_${USERSPACE_ARCH}.img
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} flash rootfs ${PRODUCT_OUT}/rootfs_${USERSPACE_ARCH}.img
try ${FASTBOOT_CMD} reboot
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I have the exact same problem!

Comment: I in the end followed: https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md and added a package for all my components.